# Buttons in a same row

Tags: button, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here my code in sencha touch, i tried to add 2 button horizontaly, Means one to other.No,luck its keep on coming one in upper side and the other one lower.

```
 var profilese = {
            standardSubmit : false,
            items: [tab,{
                    xtype:  'button',
                    text:   'ADD',
                    ui: 'confirm',
                    handler: function() {
                    view.setActiveItem(2, {type:'fade', direction:'right'});
                    }
                    },{
                    xtype:  'DELETE',
                    text:   'Search Friends',
                    ui: 'Search',
                    handler: function() {
                    view.setActiveItem(3, {type:'fade', direction:'right'});
                    }
                    }]
                };
```

How to set button in a same row.Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? What type of container are you putting profilese in? Also - what is 'tab'? Are you trying to put two buttons below this 'tab' component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `tab` is in your code, but what you need to get the buttons aligned horizontally is an `hbox` layout:

```
layout: 'hbox',
items: [
    {
        xtype:  'button',
        text:   'ADD',
        ui: 'confirm',
        handler: function() {
            view.setActiveItem(2, {type:'fade', direction:'right'});
        }
    },{
        xtype:  'button',
        text:   'Search Friends',
        ui: 'Search',
        handler: function() {
            view.setActiveItem(3, {type:'fade', direction:'right'});
        }
    }
]
```

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.HBox

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS point, there must be a container as parent to hold the children(Buttons). And the set the layout config as "hbox".

The code must look like,

```
  items:[
  tab,
  {
   xtype:'container',
   layout:'hbox',
   items:[
    {
      xtype:'button1'
    },
    { 
      xtype:'button2'
    }
   ]
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
layout: {
    type: 'column'
  },
items: [
    {
        xtype:  'button',
        columnWidth: 0.5,
        text:   'ADD',
        ui: 'confirm',
        handler: function() {
            view.setActiveItem(2, {type:'fade', direction:'right'});
        }
    },{
        xtype:  'button',
        columnWidth: 0.5,
        text:   'Search Friends',
        ui: 'Search',
        handler: function() {
            view.setActiveItem(3, {type:'fade', direction:'right'});
        }
    }
]
```