# How create textfields in one line of AEM dialog (Classic UI)

Tags: extjs, aem

[image: AEM Dialog Image]

In the above the fields are in 2 rows. I want both of them to be in one row.

Code used is:

```
<provinces jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Province List" name="./provinces" xtype="multifield">
<fieldConfig
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="multifieldpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <code
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Code"
            key="code"
            xtype="textfield"/>
        <name
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Name"
            key="name"
            xtype="textfield"/>
    </items>
</fieldConfig>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `hbox` layout for your multifield. Add `layout="hbox"` to the node with `xtype="multifieldpanel"` and it should work.

> Tested on my AEM 6.3 local instance

your specific dialog code becomes:

```
<fieldConfig
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    layout="hbox"
    xtype="multifieldpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <code
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Code"
            key="code"
            xtype="textfield"/>
        <name
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Name"
            key="name"
            xtype="textfield"/>
    </items>
</fieldConfig>
```

> If you're interested in documentation, see the [`layout` config option in the `CQ.form.MultiField` ExtJs documentation for AEM](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.MultiField). You might be interested in the other layout options.
>
> For future reference, when you have questions about classic UI widgets, try searching for that issue with `extjs` keyword, you'll find many articles that might help. For example, for this solution, I got the hint from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401887/buttons-in-a-same-row) and I found that SO question by searching "extjs in same row" then looked up the extjs AEM docs to see if there was a layout option for the multifield widget.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to create custom xtype : [how to create custom xtype](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-xtype.html)

I would recommend just to change width of the fields. You could use `width` property

```
<code
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Code"
    key="code"
    width="100%"
    xtype="textfield"/>
<name
    cr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Name"
    key="name"
    width="100%"
    xtype="textfield"/>
```

You will get something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS in your custom clientlib

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. Like what changes should be there?